# Can dogs have almond milk?

Tags: dogs, diet

It may be the case the dogs can drink cows milk, but is almond and/or soy milk bad for your dog? Is it only bad in excess? I typically allow my dog to clean my breakfast bowl when I'm done, but I haven't seen harsh side effects as of yet.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer: I’m not a vet or animal nutritionist etc.** 
This is only from what I’ve read having my own dogs.

In small doses cows milk is fine, the lactose can horrible effects for dogs and can cause upset stomachs.

If it is unsweetened almond/soy milk it’s probably fine, sweetener can contain Xylitol which is incredibly poisonous to dogs.

Xylitol is an artificial sweetener and can be found in lots of food products like milk and peanut butter.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/doghealthcoach.com/food/can-dogs-drink-almond-milk/amp/ and https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.petsbest.com/blog/is-almond-or-soy-milk-safe-for-pets/amp/ agree that almond milk and soy milk are edible for dogs, at least in small amounts, and it must not have Xylitol in it. Dogs can be allergic to both nuts and soy, so cease giving the dog the milk if you notice allergy symptoms.  And of course, they aren't the best nutritionally, but if it's just eating the dregs of your cereal bowls, I imagine that's not very much anyways.